# Getting current URL handlebars in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, keystonejs

As the title says I am trying to find the best way to get current url so I can insert a special id for a div tag. I am using the keystone.js framework.

i.e `(if page == index) { "page--index-" }`

Comment: Where are you trying to do this comparison?  In your Express code?  In your Handlebars template?  In your Express code, any request will have `req.url` or `req.originalUrl` that represents the actual request URL.  Doc for that [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl).

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your reply. I guess I am looking for req.originalUrl then creating a handlebar helper off the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the Express request, you can use [`req.originalUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) to see what the actual URL was for the request.  You can then either use a handlebar helper method or just set a property that you pass to the handlebar template rendering in order to use that information to affect the rendering of your page.